# jqGrid getLocalRow return false

Tags: jqgrid

I'm creating a JQgrid with datatype local and I want to get row values from editing row using  getLocalRow or getCell but I always get false. 
This is my grid definition:

```
jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({  
    datatype: 'local',
    data: mydata,

    loadtext:"Cargando...",
    height: altura*0.4,
    width: anchoDefecto*0.9,
    colNames:['Cuenta',
              'Subcuenta',
              'Importe',
              'Signo',
              'Clave',
              'Documento',
              'Doc. Referencia',
              'Ampliación',
              'Extensión'],
    colModel:[
            {name:'intIdfCuenta',index:'intIdfCuenta', width:200, sorttype:"int", editable:true,editrules:{required:true}, edittype:'custom', 
                editoptions:{custom_element: myelemcuentas, custom_value:myvaluecuentas} },
            {name:'intIdfSubcuenta',index:'intIdfSubcuenta', width:200,editable: true,editrules:{required:true}, edittype:'custom', 
                    editoptions:{custom_element: myelemsubcuentas, custom_value:myvaluesubcuentas}},
            {name:'floatImporte',index:'floatImporte', width:200,editable: true,editrules:{required:true}, edittype:'text'},
            {name:'strSigno',index:'strSigno', width:200,editable: true, edittype:'custom',editrules:{required:true}, 
                editoptions:{custom_element: myelemsigno, custom_value:myvaluesigno} },
            {name:'strIdfClave',index:'strIdfClave', width:200,editable: true,editrules:{required:true}, edittype:'custom', 
                    editoptions:{custom_element: myelemclave, custom_value:myvalueclave} },
            {name:'strDocumento',index:'strDocumento', width:200,editable: true,editrules:{required:true},edittype:'text'},
            {name:'strDocumentoReferencia',index:'strDocumentoReferencia', width:200,editable: true,edittype:'text'},
            {name:'strAmpliacion',index:'strAmpliacion', width:200,editable: true,edittype:'text',editoptions: {
            dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).focus(function () { this.select(); }) },
            dataEvents: [
                {
                    type: 'keydown',
                    fn: function (e) {
                        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
                        if (key == 9)
                        {
                           procesarTabulacionAmpliacion();
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
            }
            },
            {name:'strIdfTipoExtension',index:'strIdfTipoExtension', width:200,editable:true,edittype:'custom', 
                editoptions:{custom_element: myelemextension, custom_value:myvalueextension} }
            ],
    cellsubmit: "clientArray",  
    pager:"#pager",
    onSelectRow: function(id){          
        selectNextRow(id);

    }
});
```

The onSelectRow function is:

```
function selectNextRow(id){     
     if (lastsel!=null && id!==lastsel && !myRowIsValid(lastsel) ) {
         if(lastsel!=null && id!==lastsel){
             jQuery('#rowed5').jqGrid('setSelection', lastsel);
         }
         return false;
     }else if(id && id!==lastsel){      
         newline = '0';         
        jQuery("#rowed5").saveRow(lastsel, false, 'clientArray');
        jQuery("#rowed5").editRow(id, false);

        lastsel=id;
        actsel = id;
        // ponemos foco
        $(getId("intIdfCuenta",actsel,true)).focus();
    }
}
```

I try to get row info using:

```
            var floatImporte = $("#rowed5").jqGrid('getCell', 'floatImporte');
            var localRowData = $("#rowed5").jqGrid('getLocalRow');
```

But in both case I always get false.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

The method `getLocalRow` has one parameter: `rowid`. So the correct usage of `getLocalRow` is

```js
var localRowData = $("#rowed5").jqGrid('getLocalRow', id);
```

If you call `getLocalRow` without the parameter the `getLocalRow` sees `rowid` as `undefined` and can't return you the data for the corresponding row. In the case the `getLocalRow` returns `false`.

Comment: Sorry but it is not the solution. If I use:
var localRowData = $("#rowed5").jqGrid('getLocalRow',1);

I get the same result: false

Comment: @Rafael: It means that `1` is not an id from jqGrid. You should post the code where it's clear **where** (in which context) you use `getLocalRow`. Additionally post of some simple test data (`mydata`) could be helpful too. Till now you posted long code, but it don't contain any call of `getLocalRow` which is your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue and just created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqneopvz/2/). You can change some some values by clicking on a row. The problem is that "getLocalRow" always returns false because the rowid is not found. I look a little bit into the code and in jquery.jqGrid.src.js there is the row:

```
ind = this.p._index[stripPref(this.p.idPrefix, rowid)];
```

it is called with rowid="a_jqg2" for example where this.p.idPrefix is "a_".

Am I using it wrong?

Dennis